# "The email has already been taken" - Register

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

-Laravel 7. -Php 7.4 -Empty user table. im trying to clean cashe " php artisan config:clear"

[env-db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ7eW.png)     [RegisterController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DsoU.png)
      [User.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cafv4.png)

Comment: you want to clear user database table ?

Comment: No. I want to create user. to create roles and middleware

Answer (score 0):

You already have a user with the email, just try with another email